# Why hook_user_logout is not working?

Tags: 7

I am trying to display message or run some other action when user logout and redirect them to home page. I am trying following code, but all I get is just set_message and it never logoff me. why?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_logout().
 *
 */
function ucenter_user_logout($account) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Thanks for visiting, come again!'));
  drupal_goto();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `drupal_goto()`, you are avoiding the session is destroyed. The function that invokes `hook_user_logout()` ([user_logout()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_logout/7)) contains the following code.

```
  watchdog('user', 'Session closed for %name.', array('%name' => $user->name));
  module_invoke_all('user_logout', $user);

  // Destroy the current session, and reset $user to the anonymous user.
  session_destroy();

  drupal_goto();
```

[drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) calls [drupal_exit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7), which means that with your Drupal's execution is interrupted before `session_destroy()` is called.

What you can do is changing the code to something similar to the following one.

```
function ucenter_user_logout($account) {
  user_cookie_save(array('ucenter.logoff' => '1'));
}

function ucenter_init() {
  // Check the value of the cookie Drupal_visitor_ucenter_logoff
  // and print the message if the user precedently logged off.
}
```

Comment: Hi kiamlaluno, I just want to display a message, when user logout, How to do that? As I know, hook_user_logout can not use drupal_set_message

Comment: You cannot use `drupal_set_message()` because the messages are saved in the session, which is then destroyed. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine now. but its not working when I add a condition: if($_COOKIE['Drupal.visitor.ucenter.logoff'] == 1){drupal_set_message('hello')}, whats wrong?

Comment: I know why, need to replace '.' to '_', if($_COOKIE['Drupal_visitor_ucenter_logoff'] == 1),thank you very much

Comment: The name of the cookie you read with `$_COOKIE` is Drupal_visitor_ucenter_logoff; the dots are replaced with underscores, when the cookie is saved in the browser.